# Cycling through 2 lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to cycle through 2 different list, based on whether one of the lists has finished a cycle. Specifically, I want to change the symbols and colors of data points in my plot.

This is currently what I am doing:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
markers = itertools.cycle(['.', '1', '+', 'x'])
colors = itertools.cycle(['r', 'g'])

classes = ["class 1"] * 5 + ["class 2"] * 5 + ["class 3"] * 7
vals = [1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5] + [2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5] + [3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6]
vals2 = [x**2 for x in vals]
p_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": classes, "vals": vals, "vals2": vals2})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for label, df in p_df.groupby('class'):
    df.plot.scatter(x='vals', y='vals2', ax=ax, label=label, color=next(colors), marker=next(markers))
plt.legend()
```

But it is not what I want, as I am iterating through markers at the same time as colors. I want to finish iterating the colors first, then move to the next marker. So the sequence is as such

1st plot, '.' marker, 'r' color

2nd plot, '.' marker, 'g' color

3rd plot, '1' marker, 'r' color

4th plot, '1' marker, 'g' color

... and so on

One way that I thought of is to track the number of plots already done, and from there, call next on marker. But that does not seem like a good method to iterate through more complicated plots with more for loops for plotting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: islice(cycle(product(markers, colors)), N) if you want them to follow that pattern and repeat for a count N. Or just https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product if that's all you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem and so `matplotlib` now includes [cycler](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/), for composing this kind of thing. You can then replace your `itertools.cycles` like so

```
import pandas as pd
from cycler import cycler
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

markers = cycler(marker='.1+x')
colors = cycler(color='rg')

style = iter(markers * colors)

classes = ["class 1"] * 5 + ["class 2"] * 5 + ["class 3"] * 7
vals = [1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5] + [2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5] + [3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6]
vals2 = [x**2 for x in vals]
p_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": classes, "vals": vals, "vals2": vals2})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for label, df in p_df.groupby('class'):
    df.plot.scatter(x='vals', y='vals2', ax=ax, label=label, **next(style))
plt.legend()
```

To see how the cycle is composed you can do

```
for i in (markers * colors):
    print(i)
```

which prints

```
{'marker': '.', 'color': 'r'}
{'marker': '.', 'color': 'g'}
{'marker': '1', 'color': 'r'}
{'marker': '1', 'color': 'g'}
{'marker': '+', 'color': 'r'}
{'marker': '+', 'color': 'g'}
{'marker': 'x', 'color': 'r'}
{'marker': 'x', 'color': 'g'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
# Replace the itertools.cycle(...) lines with:
linetype = itertools.product('.1+x', 'rg')

...

for label, df in p_df.groupby('class'):
    (marker, color) = next(linetype)
    df.plot.scatter(x='vals', y='vals2', ax=ax, label=label, color=color, marker=marker)
```

And as pointed out in a comment (sorry, can't attribute as it's been deleted), if you need to reuse combinations, you can always wrap it in `itertools.cycle()`:

```
linetype = itertools.cycle(itertools.product('.1+x', 'rg'))
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib's `cycler` allows to automatically cycle through the properties. But this only works for `plot` (not `scatter`). However, a single colored scatter is anyways more efficiently produced with a `plot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


markers = plt.cycler(marker=['.', '1', '+', 'x'])
colors = plt.cycler(color=['r', 'g'])

classes = ["class 1"] * 5 + ["class 2"] * 5 + ["class 3"] * 7
vals = [1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5] + [2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5] + [3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6]
vals2 = [x**2 for x in vals]
p_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": classes, "vals": vals, "vals2": vals2})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.set_prop_cycle(markers*colors)
for label, df in p_df.groupby('class'):
    ax.plot("vals", "vals2", linestyle="", data=df)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```